# Capitalize text input on Fabric JS

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I have an HTML5 canvas which I intend writing on. I am using FabricJS. However, I want the text input to be in uppercase without the user having to use "caps lock".

I have tried

textbox.hiddenTextarea.autoCapitalize = "on";

and

let textbox = new fabric.IText("", {
            textAlign: "center",
            autoCapitalize: "on",

}

I also even tried :

textbox.hiddenTextarea.onkeyup = (e) => {
            e.target.value = e.target.value.toUpperCase(); }

and nothing works. What is the proper way to do what I'm trying to achieve? Or is there any hack? Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same, but I don't think there is a autoCapitalize attribute on fabric.js IText. At list is not there in the doc. Where you got that attribute from?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this syntax.
Kindly get activeObject then.

```
activeObject.set('fontCharacterStyle', 'Caps');
```

Comment: It's not working, do you have any documentation about this property on fabricjs ?

Comment: @ThoBuiNgoc thanks to commenting, but dear I have used same code in my project for fabricjs 3.1.0 version, it is working for me

Comment: Do you need customize fabricjs to use this property setting ? I'm looked for this property in fabricjs source code, but I can't found this property. Can you give me a demo code to resolve this problem ? Thank you!

Comment: I did not do anything or customisation, I have just chosen fabricjs 3.1.0 for my project and simply get activeobject of text and used this code.

activeObject.set('fontCharacterStyle', 'Caps');

Answer (score 0):

I have created a subclass of IText to allow setting textTransformation to uppercase:

```
const TransformableText = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.IText, {
  _splitTextIntoLines: function() {
    const transformedText = this.textTransform === 'uppercase' ? this.text.toUpperCase() : this.text;

    return this.callSuper('_splitTextIntoLines', transformedText);
  },
});
```

Can be used as:

```
const textbox = new TransformableText("", { textTransform: "uppercase" });
```